# How to remove the search field in custom taxonomy ui?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

In recent versions of wordpress I see a new search/autocomplete text field on top the custom taxonomy metabox (when hierarchical). I also see the taxonomy slug with it ("project_type" in the attached image).

How can I remove It? Is there an argument for that when registering the taxonomy?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove the search box? Note that `project_type` is used because you haven't set up the appropriate labels when registering the taxonomy so it's falling back to the slug, specifically the `search_items` label is missing or has a bad value,

Comment: Oh thanks for the search_items label tip. It works. On the search box, I just find it annoying in this particular case.